# Submit form from main

Tags: jquery, html, forms, grails

I'm using the newest version of grails (2.4.0).
I'm working on applicant form registration. So the header of page is loaded from view/layout/main. On each page of applicant form, I used  tag to submit to controller base on the following:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method='post' id='myform'>

        <button type='submit' onclick="submitForm('#myform', ${createlink: action:'applicantInfo1'})">
            previous page
        </button>
        <button type='submit' onclick="submitForm('#myform', ${createlink: action:'applicantInfo3'})">
            next page
        </button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(id, action){
        $(id).attr('action', action);
        $(id).submitForm();
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works, but now I have to implement the navigation bar (form1 -- form2 -- ... -form 10) and I put it on main page. So it means that I have to remove form from on each page and put form in main:

```
<form method='post'>
<g:layoutResource/>
</form>
```

On this one, when I create a button with `type=submit onlick='submitForm('myform', action)` (like above), it doesn't work, I just work when I put the action to `<form>`

Please help me to get through this stack. It's hard to create fiddle demo with it, so I brought the hold code here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by editing the form's action attribute:

```
onclick="$('form').attr('action', 'some url').submit();return false;"
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59W9E/)

Comment: Thanks for interesting with my topic. But your demo not work on the main. :(. I dont know what is missing because i use firebug to check, name and url are the same as submit form from each template.

Comment: @TranTam I have updated the code please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [actionSubmit](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.0/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) button, there you can specify `action` like:

```
<g:form controller="myController">
    <g:actionSubmit value="Previous Page" action="applicantInfo1"/>
    <g:actionSubmit value="Next Page" action="applicantInfo3"/>
</g:form>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried actionSubmit few days ago, but I redirected to index all the time.